# Pull data from table then echo it in descending order

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have the following table in my database
[click to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVpin.png)

I'm looking to find everyone whose `user_group` is "member", then put their ratings in an array and print their names in descending order based on their rating.
So in the example given, it would output `ted67945<br>ted67942`.

I currently have this code

```
function getInfo($info, $given_username) { // This is only used to get the rating of the given user
  require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/movies/scripts/db.php");
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT ".$info." FROM members WHERE username='$given_username'");
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { // for each member
    return $row[$info];
  }
}
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT username FROM members WHERE user_group='member'") or die(mysql_error());
$ratings = Array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { // for each member
  $name = $row['username'];
  if(!empty($name)) {
    array_push($ratings, getInfo("rating", $name)); // This puts all people's ratings in group "member", into an array
  }
}
rsort($ratings);
foreach($ratings as $x) {
  echo $x . "<br>";
}
```

This, obviously, outputs the numbers. How would I use this to output the names based on their rating?

Comment: I can't get the name using the rating because two or more people may share the same rating

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: I didn't put any POST or GET data into my database +tadman?

Comment: `$given_username` surely comes from a user, and you just inject it into your query. Even if that value is screened somehow, this is an extremely bad habit to get into. All it takes is one lapse where user-supplied information is injected and someone can crack your application wide open.

Comment: I added the note about the object-oriented interface because you made the common mistake of calling `mysql_error` instead of `mysqli_error`. That one letter slip means you're calling the wrong library. `$conn->error` is not subject to the same sort of issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you just use ORDER BY in your SQL request?

```
SELECT username FROM members WHERE user_group='member' ORDER BY rating DESC;
```

This will sort your data by rating in descending order. [See more](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp).

Comment: I had no idea that was a thing! Thanks! I'll accept answer as soon as it'll allow me (4mins)